# Decode an MQTT message

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt, iot

I've been working on an IoT project for a while in which I needed to save messages published by client before it reaches the broker. So I did some coding and by using sockets I was able to forward messages from client to broker but when I tried to read messages I couldn't decode those sent by clients.
In cases when a message was sent from broker to client, the message and its topic was readable:

[image: Message from broker to client is on last line]

But when client was sending data it wasn't:

[image]

On the other hand I can't distinguish published messages from others. Is there a way to decode these messages without using MQTT clients in Python?

Comment: Have you tried reading the MQTT spec?

Comment: @hardillb I have but couldn't find a way to decode it...

Comment: It clearly explains the format of every type of MQTT packet, so you need to look at that and have a go, what you are printing out is a representation of the bytes that make up each message.

Comment: maybe better use MQTT clients in Python

Comment: Also why do you think a proxy is the best way to solve this and not say using a broker that supports plugins that will let you save the messages actually in the broker?

Comment: @hardillb The problem is that although I have thought of these solutions the people I'm working with have some ideas in mind and to meet the requirements which PO asked for, I can't use this option. But I will try reading the spec again...

Comment: @furas I have considered that but based on the current structure of the project that won't be ideal...

Comment: maybe it will be not ideal but it may work. You could also check source code to get code only code which decode it.

Comment: If the MQTT message is cyphered (using TLS) there's no way you're going to be able to decode them without the proper certificates

Comment: @somerandomITboy It's not using TLS or secure socket and even if it used encryption, these messages wouldn't be encrypted cause they are the outputs that socket provides